# Structure of quotients of the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, quotient-group

We denote $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ be the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ (i.e. $\{a∈\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}:\gcd (a,n)=1\}$). We know that if $n=p_1^{k_1}\dots p_r^{k_r}$, then

$$\mathbb{Z}_n^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p_1^{k_1}}^*\times\dots\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_r^{k_r}}^*.$$

What I am interested in is the structure of the quotient groups of $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, in other words $\mathbb{Z}_n^*/\langle q\rangle$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$. I want to the determine the structure when $\langle q\rangle$ is a subgroup of two or more of the factors $\mathbb{Z}_{p_i^{k_i}}^*$.

Say we have $n=2^{15}-1=7\cdot31\cdot151$, so we know that the order of 2 is 15 by $2^{15}\equiv 1\mod n$. We also know that $\mathbb{Z}_n^*\simeq \mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_{30} \times \mathbb{Z}_{150}$. Then there are two options, either $\mathbb{Z}_n^*/\langle 2\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{150}$ or to $\mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_{30} \times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$. These two groups are not isomorphic. How can I know which one is the case? Is there a general method we can employ by looking at the group structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How can I know which one is the case?"

You can search for an element of order $25$. One group has it, the other not.

Comment: The group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_{150}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$, while $\mathbb{Z}_{30}\times \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_{5}\times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$. 5 is not coprime to itself, so $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$

Comment: You are right, that makes a difference!