# Question about abelian groups and count of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

This is the question:

> a) Determine, unless isomorphic, all Abelian groups of order 1800 that contain at least one element of order 36. Justify, for each pair of such groups, that they are not isomorphic.

I have an idea, but isn't working. The idea:

> One knows that the group $G$, with $|G|= 1800 = 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 2^3$. Then for the fundamental theorem of abelian groups, one have that:
> $$ G  = \mathbb{Z} ^r \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}\times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_s} $$
> where $r, n_1, \cdots, n_s$ obey: $r\geq 0$  and $n_i \geq 2, \forall 2\leq i \leq s $.
>
> But, I founded $12$ possibities for the decomposition of $G$. But I don't know what to do more.

and the question ask for more:

> b) For all subgroup listed in a), show an element with order 36.

And here I have no idea.

If someone could help me, I'll really greteful.

Comment: Since you found $12$ possibilities, write down one here and say which element in it has order $36$.

Comment: Hint: If a group $G$ has an element $g$ of order $36$, then $g^4$ has order $9$ and $g^9$ has order $4$, so $G$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $9$ and one of order $4$

Comment: two what I was found : $ \mathbb{Z}_{4}\times \mathbb{Z}_{9} \times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$
and the other :   $ \mathbb{Z}_{4}\times \mathbb{Z}_{9} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}\times \mathbb{Z}_{5}.$
For the @alessandro ideia, the first has one element of order 36, right ? because they  have subgroup cyclic de order 4 and 9 .

Comment: Beware, the two groups you've listed don't have order $1800$, though yes, they both have an element of order 36

Comment: sorry. The right answer is : $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{9}\times\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times \mathbb{Z}_{9}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times \mathbb{Z}_{25}$. 
I was forgetting the $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

And now? Is correct my remark ?

Comment: Thaks, @alessandro.

Comment: Also $\mathbb Z_8\times \mathbb Z_9\times\mathbb Z_5\times\mathbb Z_5$ and $\mathbb Z_8\times\mathbb Z_9\times\mathbb Z_{25}$

Comment: See also [this recent post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4145366/structure-of-quotients-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-integers-modulo-n/4145465#4145465) about abelian groups of order $1800$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a finite abelian group $(G,\cdot)$ with identity $\mathbf 1$ then $$\psi(|G|)=\prod_{j=1}^m{\frak p}(e_j)$$ using the prime factorization $|G|=\prod_{j=1}^mp_j^{e_j}$ where $\psi(n)$ is the number of finite abelian groups of size $n$ up to group isomorphism and ${\frak{p}}(n)$ is the number of integer partitions of $n$. From Kronecker we have $$\mathcal P\approx\Bbb Z_{p^{a_1}}\times\cdots\times\Bbb Z_{p^{a_m}}$$ for each abelian $p$-group $\mathcal P$ of size $p^n$ and some unique integer partition $n=\sum_{i=1}^ma_i$. $$\therefore\;\psi(p^n)={\frak p}(n)$$
Again, from Kronecker, $G$ is isomorphic with the group product $G_1\times G_2\times\cdots\times G_m$ of its $m$ Sylow subgroups where $|G_j|=p_j^{e_j}$. $$\therefore\;\psi(|G|)=\psi(\prod_{j=1}^m|G_j|)=\prod_{j=1}^m\psi(p_j^{e_j})=\prod_{j=1}^m{\frak p}(e_j)$$ and thus $\psi$ is a number theoretic function.

Finally, assume $|G|=1800=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2$. $G$ has no elements of order $4$ iff the $G$ Sylow $2$ subgroup is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2\times\cdots\times\Bbb Z_2$. Therefore, $${\frak p}(3){\frak p}(2){\frak p}(2)-{\frak p}(2){\frak p}(2)=12-4=8$$ counts the number of abelian groups of size $1800$ and with an element of order $4$.